# JQuery invoice tax calculation

Tags: jquery, html

```js
function print_today() {
  var now = new Date();
  var date = ((now.getDate()<10) ? "0" : "")+ now.getDate();
  var months = new Array('Januari','Februari','Maart','April','Mei','Juni','Juli','Augustus','September','Oktober','November','December');
  function fourdigits(number) {
    return (number < 1000) ? number + 1900 : number;
  }
  var today =  date + " " + months[now.getMonth()] + " " + (fourdigits(now.getYear()));
  return today;
}

// from http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/number/round.html
function roundNumber(number,decimals) {
  var newString;// The new rounded number
  decimals = Number(decimals);
  if (decimals < 1) {
    newString = (Math.round(number)).toString();
  } else {
    var numString = number.toString();
    if (numString.lastIndexOf(".") == -1) {// If there is no decimal point
      numString += ".";// give it one at the end
    }
    var cutoff = numString.lastIndexOf(".") + decimals;// The point at which to truncate the number
    var d1 = Number(numString.substring(cutoff,cutoff+1));// The value of the last decimal place that we'll end up with
    var d2 = Number(numString.substring(cutoff+1,cutoff+2));// The next decimal, after the last one we want
    if (d2 >= 5) {// Do we need to round up at all? If not, the string will just be truncated
      if (d1 == 9 && cutoff > 0) {// If the last digit is 9, find a new cutoff point
        while (cutoff > 0 && (d1 == 9 || isNaN(d1))) {
          if (d1 != ".") {
            cutoff -= 1;
            d1 = Number(numString.substring(cutoff,cutoff+1));
          } else {
            cutoff -= 1;
          }
        }
      }
      d1 += 1;
    } 
    if (d1 == 10) {
      numString = numString.substring(0, numString.lastIndexOf("."));
      var roundedNum = Number(numString) + 1;
      newString = roundedNum.toString() + '.';
    } else {
      newString = numString.substring(0,cutoff) + d1.toString();
    }
  }
  if (newString.lastIndexOf(".") == -1) {// Do this again, to the new string
    newString += ".";
  }
  var decs = (newString.substring(newString.lastIndexOf(".")+1)).length;
  for(var i=0;i<decimals-decs;i++) newString += "0";
  //var newNumber = Number(newString);// make it a number if you like
  return newString; // Output the result to the form field (change for your purposes)
}


function update_btw(){
 var percentage = parseInt($("#Btw option:selected" ).val());
 $(".cost").html("" + percentage);
}


function update_total(){
  var subtotal = 0;
  var NewBtw = 0;
  var Totaal = 0;
  $('.price').each(function(i){
    price = $(this).html().replace("&euro;","");
    if (!isNaN(price)) subtotal += Number(price);
  });

 subtotal = parseFloat(roundNumber(subtotal,2));
 NewBtw = roundNumber(NewBtw,2);
 Totaal = roundNumber(Totaal,2);

 $('.ExclPrice').html("&euro;"+subtotal);
   
 var percentage = parseInt($('.btw').val());
 NewBtw = parseFloat(subtotal * (percentage / 100));
 Totaal = parseFloat(subtotal + NewBtw);
 
 $('.price').html("&euro;"+Totaal);

 $('#total').html("&euro;"+Totaal);  
   
  update_balance();
}


function update_balance() {
  var due = $("#total").html();
  due = roundNumber(due,2);

  $('.due').html("&euro;"+due);

  
}

function update_price() {
  var row = $(this).parents('.item-row');
  var price = row.find('.cost').val().replace("$","") * row.find('.qty').val();
  price = roundNumber(price,2);
  isNaN(price) ? row.find('.price').html("N/A") : row.find('.price').html(""+price);
  
  update_total();
}

function bind() {
  $(".cost").blur(update_price);
  $(".qty").blur(update_price);
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('input').click(function(){
    $(this).select();
  });

  $("#paid").blur(update_balance);
   
  $("#addrow").click(function(){
    $(".item-row:last").after('<tr class="item-row"><td class="item-name"><div class="delete-wpr"><textarea>Product</textarea><a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Verwijder">X</a></div></td><td class="description"><textarea>Omschrijving</textarea></td><td><textarea class="cost">0</textarea></td><td><textarea class="qty">0</textarea></td><td><span class="ExclPrice">650,00</span></td><td><textarea class="btw">0%</textarea></td><td><span class="price">0</span></td></tr>');
    if ($(".delete").length > 0) $(".delete").show();
    bind();
  });
  
  bind();
  
  $(".delete").live('click',function(){
    $(this).parents('.item-row').remove();
    update_total();
    if ($(".delete").length < 2) $(".delete").hide();
  });
  
  $("#cancel-logo").click(function(){
    $("#logo").removeClass('edit');
  });
  $("#delete-logo").click(function(){
    $("#logo").remove();
  });
  $("#change-logo").click(function(){
    $("#logo").addClass('edit');
    $("#imageloc").val($("#image").attr('src'));
    $("#image").select();
  });
  $("#save-logo").click(function(){
    $("#image").attr('src',$("#imageloc").val());
    $("#logo").removeClass('edit');
  });
  
  $("#date").val(print_today());
  
});
```

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body { font: 13px/1.4 Arial; }
#page-wrap { width: 800px; margin: 0 auto; }

textarea { border: 0; font: 13px Arial; overflow: hidden; resize: none; }
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
table td, table th { border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px; }

#header { height: 15px; width: 100%; margin: 20px 0; background: #F33F3F; text-align: center; color: white; font: bold 15px Helvetica, Sans-Serif; text-decoration: uppercase; letter-spacing: 20px; padding: 8px 0px; }

#address { position:absolute; top:200px; width: 250px; height: 150px; text-align:left;  float: left; }
#customer { overflow: hidden; }

#logo { text-align: right; float: left; position: relative; margin-top: 25px; border: 1px solid #fff; max-width: 540px; max-height: 100px; overflow: hidden; }
#logo:hover, #logo.edit { border: 1px solid #000; margin-top: 0px; max-height: 125px; }
#logoctr { display: none; }
#logo:hover #logoctr, #logo.edit #logoctr { display: block; text-align: right; line-height: 25px; background: #eee; padding: 0 5px; }
#logohelp { text-align: left; display: none; font-style: italic; padding: 10px 5px;}
#logohelp input { margin-bottom: 5px; }
.edit #logohelp { display: block; }
.edit #save-logo, .edit #cancel-logo { display: inline; }
.edit #image, #save-logo, #cancel-logo, .edit #change-logo, .edit #delete-logo { display: none; }


#meta { margin-top: 1px; width: 300px; float: right; }
#meta td { text-align: right;  }
#meta td.meta-head { text-align: left; background: #eee; }
#meta td textarea { width: 100%; height: 20px; text-align: right; }

#items { clear: both; width: 100%; margin: 80px 0 0 0; border: 1px solid black; }
#items th { background: #eee; }
#items textarea { width: 80px; height: 50px; }
#items tr.item-row td { border: 0; vertical-align: top; }
#items td.description { width: 300px; }
#items td.item-name { width: 175px; }
#items td.description textarea, #items td.item-name textarea { width: 100%; }
#items td.total-line { border-right: 0; text-align: right; }
#items td.total-value { border-left: 0; padding: 10px; }
#items td.total-value textarea { height: 20px; background: none; }
#items td.balance { background: #eee; }
#items td.blank { border: 0; }

#terms { text-align: center; margin: 20px 0 0 0; }
#terms h5 { text-transform: uppercase; font: 13px Helvetica, Sans-Serif; letter-spacing: 10px; border-bottom: 1px solid black; padding: 0 0 8px 0; margin: 0 0 8px 0; }
#terms textarea { width: 100%; text-align: center;}

textarea:hover, textarea:focus, #items td.total-value textarea:hover, #items td.total-value textarea:focus, .delete:hover { background-color:#EEFF88; }

.delete-wpr { position: relative; }
.delete { display: block; color: #000; text-decoration: none; position: absolute; background: #EEEEEE; font-weight: bold; padding: 0px 3px; border: 1px solid; top: -6px; left: -22px; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 12px; }
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

  
  <table id="items">
  
    <tr>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Price per qty</th>
        <th>qty</th>
     <th>Price no tax</th>
     <th>Tax%</th>
        <th>Price with tax</th>
    </tr>
    
    <tr class="item-row">
        <td class="item-name"><div class="delete-wpr"><textarea>Hardware</textarea><a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a></div></td>
        <td class="description"><textarea>reperation</textarea></td>
        <td><textarea class="cost">&euro;650,00</textarea></td>
        <td><textarea class="qty">1</textarea></td>
     <td><span class="ExclPrice">&euro;650,00</span></td>
     <td><textarea class="btw">0%</textarea></td>
        <td><span class="price">&euro;650,00</span></td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr id="hiderow">
      <td colspan="7"><a id="addrow" href="javascript:;" title="Add a row"><img src="../img/icons/icon-add-product.png"></a></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="blank"></td>
        <td colspan="4" class="total-line">Totaal</td>
        <td class="total-value"><div id="total"></div></td>
    </tr>    
  </table>
```

Hello guys I stuck with a problem when I want to calculate the tax in my html Jquery invoice. The problem comes when I want to add the second row for example in the firts row the user has put 21% in and in the second 6% it will calculate the 21%. I also put a link in to see the problem and code.

```js
function update_total() {
  var subtotal = 0;

  $('.price').each(function(i) {
    price = $(this).html().replace("&euro;", "");
    if (!isNaN(price)) subtotal += Number(price);
  });

  subtotal = parseFloat(roundNumber(subtotal, 2));



  var percentage = parseInt($('.btw').val());

  var BtwPercentage = parseFloat(price * (percentage / 100));

  var InclBtw = parseFloat(price) + parseFloat(BtwPercentage);


  $('.ExclPrice').html("&euro;" + subtotal);

  $('.price').html("&euro;" + InclBtw);



  update_balance();
}


function update_balance() {
  var due = $("#total").html();
  due = roundNumber(due, 2);

  $('.due').html("&euro;" + due);


}

function update_price() {
  var row = $(this).parents('.item-row');
  var price = row.find('.cost').val().replace("$", "") * row.find('.qty').val();
  price = roundNumber(price, 2);
  isNaN(price) ? row.find('.price').html("N/A") : row.find('.price').html("" + price);

  update_total();
}

function bind() {
  $(".cost").blur(update_price);
  $(".qty").blur(update_price);
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('input').click(function() {
    $(this).select();
  });

  $("#paid").blur(update_balance);

  $("#addrow").click(function() {
    $(".item-row:last").after('<tr class="item-row"><td class="item-name"><div class="delete-wpr"><textarea>Product</textarea><a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Verwijder">X</a></div></td><td class="description"><textarea>Omschrijving</textarea></td><td><textarea class="cost">0</textarea></td><td><textarea class="qty">0</textarea></td><td><span class="ExclPrice">650,00</span></td><td><textarea class="btw">0%</textarea></td><td><span class="price">0</span></td></tr>');
    if ($(".delete").length > 0) $(".delete").show();
    bind();
  });

  bind();

  $(".delete").live('click', function() {
    $(this).parents('.item-row').remove();
    update_total();
    if ($(".delete").length < 2) $(".delete").hide();
  });

  $("#cancel-logo").click(function() {
    $("#logo").removeClass('edit');
  });
  $("#delete-logo").click(function() {
    $("#logo").remove();
  });
  $("#change-logo").click(function() {
    $("#logo").addClass('edit');
    $("#imageloc").val($("#image").attr('src'));
    $("#image").select();
  });
  $("#save-logo").click(function() {
    $("#image").attr('src', $("#imageloc").val());
    $("#logo").removeClass('edit');
  });

  $("#date").val(print_today());

});
```

```css
        * {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
        }
        body {
          font: 13px/1.4 Arial;
        }
        #page-wrap {
          width: 800px;
          margin: 0 auto;
        }
        textarea {
          border: 0;
          font: 13px Arial;
          overflow: hidden;
          resize: none;
        }
        table {
          border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        table td,
        table th {
          border: 1px solid black;
          padding: 5px;
        }
        #header {
          height: 15px;
          width: 100%;
          margin: 20px 0;
          background: #F33F3F;
          text-align: center;
          color: white;
          font: bold 15px Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
          text-decoration: uppercase;
          letter-spacing: 20px;
          padding: 8px 0px;
        }
        #address {
          position: absolute;
          top: 200px;
          width: 250px;
          height: 150px;
          text-align: left;
          float: left;
        }
        #customer {
          overflow: hidden;
        }
        #logo {
          text-align: right;
          float: left;
          position: relative;
          margin-top: 25px;
          border: 1px solid #fff;
          max-width: 540px;
          max-height: 100px;
          overflow: hidden;
        }
        #logo:hover,
        #logo.edit {
          border: 1px solid #000;
          margin-top: 0px;
          max-height: 125px;
        }
        #logoctr {
          display: none;
        }
        #logo:hover #logoctr,
        #logo.edit #logoctr {
          display: block;
          text-align: right;
          line-height: 25px;
          background: #eee;
          padding: 0 5px;
        }
        #logohelp {
          text-align: left;
          display: none;
          font-style: italic;
          padding: 10px 5px;
        }
        #logohelp input {
          margin-bottom: 5px;
        }
        .edit #logohelp {
          display: block;
        }
        .edit #save-logo,
        .edit #cancel-logo {
          display: inline;
        }
        .edit #image,
        #save-logo,
        #cancel-logo,
        .edit #change-logo,
        .edit #delete-logo {
          display: none;
        }
        #meta {
          margin-top: 1px;
          width: 300px;
          float: right;
        }
        #meta td {
          text-align: right;
        }
        #meta td.meta-head {
          text-align: left;
          background: #eee;
        }
        #meta td textarea {
          width: 100%;
          height: 20px;
          text-align: right;
        }
        #items {
          clear: both;
          width: 100%;
          margin: 80px 0 0 0;
          border: 1px solid black;
        }
        #items th {
          background: #eee;
        }
        #items textarea {
          width: 80px;
          height: 50px;
        }
        #items tr.item-row td {
          border: 0;
          vertical-align: top;
        }
        #items td.description {
          width: 300px;
        }
        #items td.item-name {
          width: 175px;
        }
        #items td.description textarea,
        #items td.item-name textarea {
          width: 100%;
        }
        #items td.total-line {
          border-right: 0;
          text-align: right;
        }
        #items td.total-value {
          border-left: 0;
          padding: 10px;
        }
        #items td.total-value textarea {
          height: 20px;
          background: none;
        }
        #items td.balance {
          background: #eee;
        }
        #items td.blank {
          border: 0;
        }
        #terms {
          text-align: center;
          margin: 20px 0 0 0;
        }
        #terms h5 {
          text-transform: uppercase;
          font: 13px Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
          letter-spacing: 10px;
          border-bottom: 1px solid black;
          padding: 0 0 8px 0;
          margin: 0 0 8px 0;
        }
        #terms textarea {
          width: 100%;
          text-align: center;
        }
        textarea:hover,
        textarea:focus,
        #items td.total-value textarea:hover,
        #items td.total-value textarea:focus,
        .delete:hover {
          background-color: #EEFF88;
        }
        .delete-wpr {
          position: relative;
        }
        .delete {
          display: block;
          color: #000;
          text-decoration: none;
          position: absolute;
          background: #EEEEEE;
          font-weight: bold;
          padding: 0px 3px;
          border: 1px solid;
          top: -6px;
          left: -22px;
          font-family: Verdana;
          font-size: 12px;
        }
```

```html
<div id="page-wrap">

  <textarea id="header">FC-IT</textarea>

  <div id="identity">

    <textarea id="address"></textarea>

    <div id="logo">

      <div id="logoctr">
        <a href="javascript:;" id="change-logo" title="Change logo">Change Logo</a>
        <a href="javascript:;" id="save-logo" title="Save changes">Save</a>
        |
        <a href="javascript:;" id="delete-logo" title="Delete logo">Delete Logo</a>
        <a href="javascript:;" id="cancel-logo" title="Cancel changes">Cancel</a>
      </div>

      <div id="logohelp">
        <input id="imageloc" type="text" size="50" value="" />
        <br />(max width: 540px, max height: 100px)
      </div>
      <img id="image" src="../img/Logo.png" alt="logo" />
    </div>

  </div>

  <div style="clear:both"></div>

  <div id="customer">
    <table id="meta">
      <tr>
        <td class="meta-head">Kvk</td>
        <td>
          <textarea></textarea>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="meta-head">BTW nummer</td>
        <td>
          <textarea></textarea>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="meta-head">Bankrekeningnummer</td>
        <td>
          <textarea></textarea>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="meta-head">Invoice #</td>
        <td>
          <textarea>
            <?php $Datum=D ate( "Y"); $Teken="-" ; $num=1 ; echo $Datum, $Teken; printf( "%03d", $num);?>
          </textarea>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>

        <td class="meta-head">Datum</td>
        <td>
          <textarea id="date">December 15, 2009</textarea>
        </td>
      </tr>

    </table>

  </div>

  <table id="items">

    <tr>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>Decription</th>
      <th>Price per qty</th>
      <th>qty</th>
      <th>Price with no tax</th>
      <th>tax%</th>
      <th>Price with tax</th>
    </tr>

    <tr class="item-row">
      <td class="item-name">
        <div class="delete-wpr">
          <textarea>Hardware</textarea><a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="description">
        <textarea>Reperatie</textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea class="cost">&euro;650,00</textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea class="qty">1</textarea>
      </td>
      <td><span class="ExclPrice">&euro;650,00</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea class="btw">0%</textarea>
      </td>
      <td><span class="price">&euro;650,00</span>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="hiderow">
      <td colspan="7">
        <a id="addrow" href="javascript:;" title="Add a row">
          <img src="../img/icons/icon-add-product.png">
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" class="blank"></td>
      <td colspan="4" class="total-line">Totaal</td>
      <td class="total-value">
        <div id="total"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <div id="terms">
    <h5><b></b></h5>
    <textarea>.</textarea>
  </div>
```

Comment: copy your code to the question.. not just a link

Comment: It would make things easier if you supplied some html along with this, so the code can be tested.

Comment: I've moved the code parts in a snippet for easier manipulations and understanding... But it would be very kind of you to remove every part of code that does not have anything to do with your question.

Comment: Tanks for reply I have just edited the code

Comment: is all this related to your question?

Comment: The first snippet is about my question